# Delete key present inside objects array via jq

Tags: json, key, jq

If I want to delete `age` from the JSON in first output. Is there a way to do that in one step, in other words, not invoking jq 2 times?

```
➜ $?=0 @arastogi-ld2.linkedin.biz inGraphs/common-templates [ 1:39AM] ➤ echo '[{"id": 1, "name": "Arthur", "age": "21"},{"id": 2, "name": "Richard", "age": "32"}]' | jq .
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Arthur",
    "age": "21"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Richard",
    "age": "32"
  }
]

>>>  0s elasped...
➜ $?=0 @arastogi-ld2.linkedin.biz inGraphs/common-templates [ 1:39AM] ➤ echo '[{"id": 1, "name": "Arthur", "age": "21"},{"id": 2, "name": "Richard", "age": "32"}]' | jq '.[] | del(.age)' | jq -s
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Arthur"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Richard"
  }
]

>>>  1s elasped...
➜ $?=0 @arastogi-ld2.linkedin.biz inGraphs/common-templates [ 1:39AM] ➤
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is quite simple when using [`jq`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/) using the `map()` call.

```
jq 'map(del(.age))' < json
```

Using `map()` for a given filter `del(.age)` will run it for each element of the input array, and return the output in a new array.